# How do I append to a global list inside of a function?

Tags: python, list, function

I have a program that I expect to extend repeatedly and don't want to have to deal with coding the same thing every time I add a new segment. The only problem is that one function I need involves appending a list defined outside of the function. I tried using globals() but got a syntax error.

An example of what I need, but doesn't work due to the nature of functions and local variables is this:

```
fruitList = []
miscList = []

newListObject = input("Enter a new object")

def listAppend(object = newListObject, fruit = fruitList):
     if object in fruit:
          fruitList.append(object)
     else:
          miscList.append(object)

listAppend()
```

This doesn't work because miscList and fruitList are global and functions can only access and especially modify local variables. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: This isn't modifying global variables, but rather modifying the objects the global variables point to.

Comment: Also, it's best not to name something `object` as that's the name of the built-in Python type that's, well, the basis of everything.

Comment: This *absolutely does work*. But it's failing for antoher reason. Please **always** include the full error message.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is correct - unless you have this code in another context, this works. This is can be demonstrated by printing the lists out after you call `listAppend`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What you say about globals is incorrect, and I can't reproduce the problem. When I try your code, I correctly see the string that I input get appended to `miscList`. As for why you "got a syntax error" using `globals()`, we can only explain that if you show the code where you tried that. It also definitely has nothing to do with "using `globals()`" - even if you had a problem related to using that, it wouldn't show up as a *syntax* error because a *syntax* error is the result of indenting your code wrongly, mismatching brackets etc.

Comment: Thank you all. I guess I just free-handed some of the more delicate stuff without testing the base concepts first. I didn't even truly test the example code. I'll keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: For future reference and advice on asking, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I already retracted that.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly works for me! Note that passing global lists as function parameters is not recommended, however there's nothing stopping you from doing that if you have a specific need for it. Example I was testing with is below.

```py
fruitList = ['test']
miscList = []


def listAppend(obj=None, fruit=fruitList, misc=miscList):
    if obj is None:
        obj = input("Enter a new object")

    if obj in fruit:
        fruit.append(obj)
    else:
        misc.append(obj)


listAppend('lol')
listAppend('test')

print(fruitList)
print(miscList)
```

Output:

```
['test', 'test']
['lol']
```

NB: I've renamed the parameter `object` to `obj`, because it's generally not a good idea to overwrite a builtin type.